# Ramifications of increased speed or force produced by muscles on the effects of a melee attack on a steel wall

Tags: physics, bio-mechanics

So I've seen questions and answers on super strength but I was wondering more about superspeed.

This superhuman can move 20 times faster than an ordinary human.
Assume this Super Human also has enhanced reflexes, vision, and thinking to handle this speed as well as the durability required to punch a steel wall and receive no bruising on their fist. Basically assume that the superspeed won't kill them and that they operate just fine even while using their super speed.
The Superhuman weighs 70 kg.

When this human decides it wants to punch a steel wall that is roughly 3 inches thick and properly anchored to the ground. What would happen to the steel wall?

Comment: "What sorts of things happen " is the sort of open ended question we try to avoid here. Give us a problem with the possibility of finding a best answer.

Comment: Is that better?

Comment: You just changed "What sorts of things happen " to "what would happen if". The question stays open ended.

Comment: ??? I'm sorry but that doesn't look at all like a what would happen if is ever mentioned but yeah i can see how it's still pretty ambiguous.nevermind that I just changed to fit that. Imma make a better question now c ya.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a question of simple physics.

A punch delivered by a normal, non-super karate practitioner might deliver as much as 450 Joule of energy.  The punch may be delivered at around 10 m/s.  Using the formula E=½mv², this gives an effective mass behind the punch of 9kg.

If we simply speed up the punch 20-fold to 200 m/s, and keep all other factors identical, we get an impact energy of 180 *kilo*joule, *400* times the impact energy.

Consulting Wikipedia's [Orders of Magnitude (Energy) table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orders_of_magnitude_(energy)), we can see that 1.8×10⁵ J, or 180 kJ is over half the impact energy of a 1 ton car moving at 89 kph, and well in excess of the impact energy of an elephant rifle (7 kJ)

A regular karateka can probably hit hard enough to make a sizeable steel plate vibrate.  As a karateka myself,  though  not a master, I can kick hard enough to make a concrete tilt-slab wall vibrate audibly.  I wouldn't want to punch one, as I'd probably break my knuckles.

Applying 400 times the energy might not allow the super to punch clear through the plate, but they'll likely put a significant dent in it, and/or they might knock it loose from whatever is holding it in place. If the plate is made from brittle metal, they might just punch a hole through it.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer I had no idea about half the math behind that.

Comment: @BIGBOLDWORDS, Exactly what would happen to the steel plate depends on the exact composition of the steel, and even its temperature.

Comment: Yup i know that which is why the question remains ambiguous at best. Steel has so many different types.

Comment: Unless the superhuman super-braces themselves somehow, what would happen is that the punch would propel them away from the plate, knocking themselves ass over teakettle, and leaving the plate largely unharmed.  "Every action has an equal and opposite reaction."  The friction of their 70 kg weight + feet on the ground is not enough to direct all that energy into the steel plate to dent it.

Comment: Thank you @GrumpyYoungMan. That is mostly what i wanted to know.

Answer (score 2):

**Assumption:** I think you're really asking only about what would happen to the wall if kicked by your speedster. I'm not going to focus on anything other than that. L.Dutch is correct that it helps tremendously for you to be very, very specific about what you're asking because explaining all the effects (like what sound it would make, or what would happen if a worm was on the ground behind the wall...) is simply way beyond the site's scope. So, I'm only going to explain whether or not the steel wall will bend due to the impact with your speedster's foot.

**Let's set the steel aside for a moment and set some expectations**

Your speedster can withstand the superpower when running, which means he/she can withstand air friction and the heat it creates.

I'm assuming we're ignoring the fact that the faster you try to move through a medium, the more "solid" it behaves, which is why belly flopping from a height is such a bad idea. At a high enough speed, the impact on water is little different from concrete. The difference is once all that kinetic energy is expended, you sink rather than your offal just sitting there on the concrete.

*While watching DC's* The Flash *I've always been entertained by the idea that as fast as he can run, the reaction to that instantaneous shift from zero to a bazillion mph would likely cause him to bounce backward onto his keester and cause a shockwave that would probably blow out nearby windows. But what fun would it be if we held superheros to the ruthless reality of physics?*

**How this relates to your question**

So, we're either ignoring the increasing impermeability of the chemical encountered by the speedster, or the speedster is capable of withstanding the physical shock of moving that fast. I like the latter idea better, because it creates a suspension-of-disbelief reason for what would happen if he kicked a steel wall. The alternative is that his/her foot would become a bloody stump. That's not fun.

What would happen is this: exactly the same thing that would happen to a normal person doing the same thing, except that it would dent or bend the wall. And it would hurt, just as it would for a normal person. The speedster isn't abnormally affected — *but the wall is.*

A Newton = 1 (Kg • m)/s<sup>2</sup>. The mass part doesn't change. The distance traveled part doesn't change. But 20X the speed means 1/20<sup>th</sup> the time... *squared.* Which means your speedster will hit the wall with 400X the force the same person would when not "sped up."

Remember, because he/she's a speedster, this effort didn't result in crushing their foot to a pulp. It simply hurts as it would if anybody walked up and kicked a steel wall. Maybe it would break a toe. It depends on the quality of his/her shoes.

But what really happens to the steel? [Holly Holm kicked Rhonda Rousey with 50 pounds of force](https://www.wired.com/2015/11/holly-holm-ronda-rousey-destroying-kick-packed-a-lot-of-force/) in a professional bout that knocked Rhonda out. That sounds like a reasonable "best case effort." 50 pounds of force is equal to 222 Newtons. Your speedster would deliver 88,800 Newtons or 20,000 pounds of force.

I'm simplifying, but that's kinda like hitting the steel wall with a 10-ton wrecking ball. But this part is important: That ball moved only one meter in one second (that's the equivalent force). Still, 10 tons, one meter, one second. And that's ignoring the actual mass, speed, and distance of the body/leg, which will only multiply the number (sheesh, if you could get all 70kg behind it and swung it two meters you'd be delivering 1,400 tons of force.... Did I do the math right? Somebody tell me I did the math right....)

Now, there are different grades of steel including stainless steels. Rather than going into all the gory details, there are likely some of those grades that wouldn't be bent. They might not even be scratched. It's a heavy ball, but it's not moving far or fast. On the other hand, there are grades of steel that would wrap around it like a proverbial sheet of tinfoil. Well, not that bad, but it would dent something awful.

But what might be interesting is how the steel wall is mounted. That much force might rip the wall right out of its mounting, letting it simply fall the the floor, giving your speedster easy access to his nemesis' evil laboratory.

Comment: Yeah point was, I was hoping for a lower-end speedster type answer where those laws of physics applied hence, the extra durability required. Anyway thanks for the great answer to a sadly still kind of ambiguous question.